# wp_title() return random number

Tags: functions, theme-development

`wp_title()` function return only one integer, 27 to be specific. On all pages it works great but one. Before I changed title it was returning 'false', further changes make no difference. Place where i call function also make no difference.

What could cause this problem?

EDIT 1: It happen after changing pages permalink.

Comment: What are you trying to get? The page ID or the page title? Or the page slug?

Comment: Page title and site title

Comment: Have you tried using `get_the_title()` instead?

Comment: It works, but it only return page title

Comment: There are also `get_bloginfo()` and `bloginfo()` you can also use them in combination with your `wp_title()`

Comment: Okay, I found that yoast plugin was causing problem, after changing title in "Snippet Preview" title changed with no problem.

PS Should I add answer and accept it?

Comment: Mann THat's Yoast's DOing, it is probably sending some random stuff to the page title